# How to solve syntax error in eclipse Mars.1

Tags: java

Here is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner

class VersatileSnitSoft
       public static void main (String [] args) {
       double amount; 

       System.out.print (*What is the price of CD-ROM? *)
       amount = myScanner.nextDouble ();
       amount = amount + 25.00;

       System.out.print(*We will bill R*);
       System.out.print(amount);
       System.out.printIn(* to your credit card.*)
     }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get errors? On which lines in your code example.

Comment: Why do think a String can be written between stars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be right in this mode.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class VersatileSnitSoft {
    public static void main (String [] args) { 
        double amount;
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print ("What is the price of CD-ROM? ");
        amount = myScanner.nextDouble ();
        amount = amount + 25.00;

        System.out.print("We will bill R ");
        System.out.print(amount);
        System.out.println(" to your credit card.");
    }
}
```

try to read some tuturial like this [Learn java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

```
  System.out.print(*What is the price of CD-ROM? *)
```

String should be wrapped in `""` not `**` and where's the semi colon at the end of this statement.

Comment: So just read it :) you just need to use " instead * and put ; to end of print command  :) 
That'S not problem of Eclipse but your syntax btw :)

Answer (score 0):

There weren't many things correct here. I suggest you start from the bottom and actually read up on how the syntax looks, how the language works.

That being said, your code now looks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class VersatileSnitSoft {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        double amount;

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print ("What is the price of CD-ROM? ");
        amount = myScanner.nextDouble ();
        amount += 25.00;

        System.out.print("We will bill R" + amount + " to your credit card.");

        myScanner.close();
    }
}
```

The changes made are:

- You never initialized the scanner, you just used it.
- You made up your own method `printIn` which doesn't exist, I suggest it was supposed to be `println (...)`
- You used `*` around a string instead of quotation `"`.
- You forgot `;` at the end of one line.
- You also have to close the `Scanner`, which I showed how now.

For the future, read the error messages and try to understand them, at least share them with us. This code now produces zero errors.